# How to customize the display of the Toolbar and Status Bar of a Table in a pandastable

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I want to customize the buttons of the original Toolbar and Status Bar of the class Table of the [pandastable](https://pypi.org/project/pandastable/). So I want to suppress some buttons and add my own buttons. I've started with the code below.

Please, any suggestions to start with?

```
import tkinter as tk
from pandastable import Table

class App(tk.Tk):                                                                                                                                            
    def __init__(self):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.creer_widgets()
        
    def creer_widgets(self):
        self.FrameH = tk.Frame(self, bd=3)
            
        self.FrameH.pack(pady=3, fill='both', expand=True)
        
        pt = Table(self.FrameH, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
        
        pt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = App()
    app.title('PandasTable Example')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I believe you have tried something, right? Or found something while doing research about your problem?

Comment: You can start by reading the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the help center. That will give you tips on how to improve your question to increase your chances to get answers.

Comment: @Xitiz Yes, I try to start with the code example above. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Look at the code of the `Toolbar` class in `pandastable/core.py` to write your own custom toolbar class and [sub-class](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#basics) the `Table` to create a table that uses your custom toolbar instead of the standard one.